# Make underlying sticky div clickable

Tags: html, css, clickable

[On this page](http://supertiny.nl/minivarkens/woordenboek/) (Wordpress site), the pink element becomes sticky when it touches the menu. But this element is unclickable because of the logo on the left, which makes the menu wrapper higher, thus making the sticky element unclickable.

I can't use `pointer-events:none` on the `menu` div, because that makes the menu + logo unclickable.

Also, `z-index` is of no use as the sticky element is nested in the content wrapper. So if I'd make the `z-index` of the content higher than the menu, the content will scroll on top of the menu.

I should probably separate the sticky element from the content wrapper, but as I'm no expert with the Wordpress wireframes, I don't know how.

Or are there any other tricks I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just set the class `fusion-logo` to `position: absolute` the logo container won't follow the normal flow of the element, so that `fusion-header` height will be the same of the navigation menu and the pink element will be right below to it, clickable

Comment: Brilliant, that did it! I always thought using 'position: absolute' would mess up the position and wouldn't work responsive so I didn't even try that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, `position: absolute` if used correctly and if you know why you're using it can create cool solutions! I'm glad that my answer helped you